# Page flip animation - Single page only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code works, but I'm not sure how to make this work for single page only. ie. when only one page is being displayed onscreen instead of two like now.

http://codepen.io/timohausmann/pen/xdKkA

```
.page {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  transition: 1.5s transform;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;  
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10% 5% 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, from(#FFFFFF), to(#CCCCCC));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fff, #ccc);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.page.active {
  z-index: 1;
}
.page.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.page.flipped:last-of-type {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: add visibility:hidden to .back if you just want to hide the second page. IMO, the flip effect wont look good with one page only.

Comment: It is possible but the big question is how do you plan to go back to the previous page if you have only one page in the screen? This would determine how simple or complex the change would have to be.

Comment: @Harry left / right swipes. Simple. Like ibooks and other apps.

Comment: And buttons for those that don't have touch enabled?

Comment: Yes maybe, but my focus is mobile only so swipes work for me.

Comment: @3zzy: [Here is a sample](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/bdMZwX). It is not quite perfect yet but I guess you get the idea. If this is what you need on a high level then let me know and I will add it as answer.

Comment: @Harry Yes, it looks good except the back animation isn't perfect, a black overlay shows up for a few ms and then it animates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert that back to back page display animation into a single page display animation by making the following changes:

- There is no need for two `div` elements (for front and back sides of the page) because  there is no back to back display. Each `section` would represent a single page in the book. The `div class='back'` can be removed totally. (**Note:** I have also renamed the `div class='front'` to `div class='content'` because front doesn't mean anything here).
- A rotation by -180deg is generally used to display the backside of the element. Since there is no backside to display in a single page flip animation, a rotation by -90deg is enough instead of a rotation by -180deg.
- A higher `z-index` is added to the flipped and active states of the element to keep the pages that are after the current page behind on the screen. `opacity: 0` is also added to them to prevent them from being visible.
- A delay is added to the `transition` (second time value in `transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s`) to prevent the `opacity` from changing before the `transform` is complete (thus avoiding the partly black screen on back movement).
- As the change from `active` state to `flipped` state should happen simultaneously, `addClass` and `removeClass` in jQuery are replaced with a single `toggleClass` call.
- The function call to move pages (for devices that don't have touch enabled) is moved from a click on the page to the usage of Previous and Next buttons.

```js
var currentPage = 0;

$('body')
  .on('click', '#next', nextPage)
  .on('click', '#prev', prevPage);

$('.book').hammer().on("swipeleft", nextPage);
$('.book').hammer().on("swiperight", prevPage);

function prevPage() {
  $('.flipped')
    .last()
    .toggleClass('flipped active')
    .siblings('.page')
    .removeClass('active');
}

function nextPage() {
  $('.active')
    .toggleClass('active flipped')
    .next('.page')
    .addClass('active');
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.scene {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.book {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.page {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10% 5% 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, from(#FFFFFF), to(#CCCCCC));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fff, #ccc);
}
.page.active {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: 1.5s transform;
  z-index: 1;
}
.page.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transition: 1.5s transform;
  z-index: 2;
}
.active ~ .page{
  opacity: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 0.1em;
  text-indent: 1em;
}
.qr {
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.qr img {
  display: block;
}
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .scene {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 5%;
  }
}
/* added for the buttons */

#next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
#prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scene">
  <article class="book">
    <section class="page active">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Quick iPad Flipping Book Demo</h1>
        <p>
          Sehen Sie, Webstandards sind das Regelwerk, auf dem Webseiten aufbauen. So gibt es Regeln für HTML, CSS, JavaScript oder auch XML; Worte, die Sie vielleicht schon einmal von Ihrem Entwickler gehört haben. Diese Standards sorgen dafür, dass alle Beteiligten
          aus einer Webseite den größten Nutzen ziehen.
        </p>
        <p>
          Im Gegensatz zu früheren Webseiten müssen wir zum Beispiel nicht mehr zwei verschiedene Webseiten für den Internet Explorer und einen anderen Browser programmieren. Es reicht eine Seite, die - richtig angelegt - sowohl auf verschiedenen Browsern im Netz
          funktioniert, aber ebenso gut für den Ausdruck oder
        </p>
        <div class="qr">
          <img src="http://www.qrcode-generator.de/getCode/?cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fcodepen.io%2Ftimohausmann%2Ffull%2FxdKkA&chs=180x180&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0" />qr code for codepen full page</div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="page">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>– 2 –</h1>
        <p>
          Sehen Sie, Webstandards sind das Regelwerk, auf dem Webseiten aufbauen. So gibt es Regeln für HTML, CSS, JavaScript oder auch XML; Worte, die Sie vielleicht schon einmal von Ihrem Entwickler gehört haben. Diese Standards sorgen dafür, dass alle Beteiligten
          aus einer Webseite den größten Nutzen ziehen.
        </p>
        <p>
          Im Gegensatz zu früheren Webseiten müssen wir zum Beispiel nicht mehr zwei verschiedene Webseiten für den Internet Explorer und einen anderen Browser programmieren. Es reicht eine Seite, die - richtig angelegt - sowohl auf verschiedenen Browsern im Netz
          funktioniert, aber ebenso gut für den Ausdruck oder
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="page">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>– 3 –</h1>
        <p>
          Sehen Sie, Webstandards sind das Regelwerk, auf dem Webseiten aufbauen. So gibt es Regeln für HTML, CSS, JavaScript oder auch XML; Worte, die Sie vielleicht schon einmal von Ihrem Entwickler gehört haben. Diese Standards sorgen dafür, dass alle Beteiligten
          aus einer Webseite den größten Nutzen ziehen.
        </p>
        <p>
          Im Gegensatz zu früheren Webseiten müssen wir zum Beispiel nicht mehr zwei verschiedene Webseiten für den Internet Explorer und einen anderen Browser programmieren. Es reicht eine Seite, die - richtig angelegt - sowohl auf verschiedenen Browsern im Netz
          funktioniert, aber ebenso gut für den Ausdruck oder
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="page">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>– 4 –</h1>
        <p>
          Sehen Sie, Webstandards sind das Regelwerk, auf dem Webseiten aufbauen. So gibt es Regeln für HTML, CSS, JavaScript oder auch XML; Worte, die Sie vielleicht schon einmal von Ihrem Entwickler gehört haben. Diese Standards sorgen dafür, dass alle Beteiligten
          aus einer Webseite den größten Nutzen ziehen.
        </p>
        <p>
          Im Gegensatz zu früheren Webseiten müssen wir zum Beispiel nicht mehr zwei verschiedene Webseiten für den Internet Explorer und einen anderen Browser programmieren. Es reicht eine Seite, die - richtig angelegt - sowohl auf verschiedenen Browsern im Netz
          funktioniert, aber ebenso gut für den Ausdruck oder
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="page">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>– 5 –</h1>
        <p>
          Sehen Sie, Webstandards sind das Regelwerk, auf dem Webseiten aufbauen. So gibt es Regeln für HTML, CSS, JavaScript oder auch XML; Worte, die Sie vielleicht schon einmal von Ihrem Entwickler gehört haben. Diese Standards sorgen dafür, dass alle Beteiligten
          aus einer Webseite den größten Nutzen ziehen.
        </p>
        <p>
          Im Gegensatz zu früheren Webseiten müssen wir zum Beispiel nicht mehr zwei verschiedene Webseiten für den Internet Explorer und einen anderen Browser programmieren. Es reicht eine Seite, die - richtig angelegt - sowohl auf verschiedenen Browsern im Netz
          funktioniert, aber ebenso gut für den Ausdruck oder
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

  </article>
  <button id='next'>Next</button>
  <button id='prev'>Previous</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There's transparency on the pages, but I guess that can be fixed by adding background-color to the container, will try that now

Comment: @3zzy: I have fixed that also. Have a look and let me know :) I remember seeing your profile pic in [this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-svg-and-designs). If you need any more help, you can find me there.

Comment: `https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-lamarr-vjpng9?file=/src/components/HuhTest.vue` for an example without `absolute` positioning