# Flip book effect behaves weird, pages falling through eachother

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a book effect, where the book will be flipped to the correct page with a 3d effect, according to the user-selected options. But as I am not really well known with 3d/transforms etc in CSS3, I've got a few issues that I'm having trouble with.

Right now I've got the following piece of code that flips a page:

```
$(document).on('click','.button', function() {
    $('#configurationPreviewContainer ul:nth-of-type('+$(this).attr('data-target')+')').css('transform', 'rotateY(-180deg) perspective(3000px)');
});
```

but see the entire html/css/JS @ codepen > http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOrjeG

In the extended version, the user does not have to click each page individually, but for this quick/clean demo I made it that way.

**There are three issues right now;**

1) When you click the 'page 1' link, the front/cover of the book will flip. But the front will still show, when the page lands? It should show the back of the cover of the book

2) The 90% rotateY is not in the center of the book, but it is a bit to the left of the book. Why is that, and how would I fix that?

3) When you first select 'page 1', and then 'page 2', the second page will fall through the first page, rendering it invisible.

Comment: I am definitely not saying that this is a duplicate but have a look at the demos (both the one in question and the one in answer) in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364296/page-flip-animation-single-page-only/31366220#31366220) and I feel that you are looking at one of those.

Comment: Thank you for that link Harry! I've searched for similar questions @ stack, but did not find that link. That is basically what I want to do, and it provides  good insight in the code used. That will surely help me solve issue 1 and 3. But it seems that in your link, they also have the same 'issue' as I have described in issue 2

Comment: Nice to know that it helped. Regarding issue 2, I am a bit lost because I couldn't see any offset from the center. I hope you are not referring to the perspective setting.

Comment: I've modified your example, to see if it works correctly when switching pages. In my final version the front of the book will be different in color from the inside pages, so it has to work correctly, and now show strange animation effects like it does now: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpJdXP - any idea why that is? You can click the 'button' in the top left to initiate the switching of pages

Comment: Didn't get you again mate. Anyway, I made the changes that were mentioned in Point 3-5 in the linked thread and I don't see anything wrong here - http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/xGNazB. Could you please pin point the exact problem?

Comment: It seems the issue I am seeing, is a browser rendering issue. I'm using OsX Yosemite, and in Chrome I see a small error in the rendering, but in Firefox all is well. In Chrome when the page lands, you can briefly see a bit of the page beneath it through the page falling on top of it. So when you press the 'button', when page 3 (yellow) lands, you can briefly see a bit of the green page through the yellow - but only on the right side of the page.. weird :)

And when you manually flip the pages, you sometimes see the page behind the one you click for 1 frame. strange as well, but render issues?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87379/discussion-between-big-men-lab-and-harry).

Comment: Sorry, can't chat now. Even on very close observation the only issue I see is a temporary *bring to front* of an earlier page (before the transform is complete) while going to the previous pages. This should be the result of some opacity/z-index issues. I am using Chrome 38 on Windows 7.

Comment: That's ok - no worries :) I think I have tackled (worked around) all weird things right now. When the site is published, I'll give the URL to you/this thread!

Comment: Good to know that you have already worked around your problem. Good luck with the rest :)